# How to 4 line from current line in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have a text file that I want to read.  It looks like this

Error: Deadlock

Param 0 = xyx

Param 1 = 22332244

Param 2 =

Param 3 = 1

Param 4 =

I need to search for String "Deadlock" and spit out output for Param 0 and Param 1.  Right now I am able only able to read line that contains text deadlock :(

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Pattern = "deadlock"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\1\Retrieve.log", ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strSearchString = objFile.ReadLine
    Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strSearchString)  
    If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        For Each strMatch in colMatches   
            Wscript.Echo strSearchString 
        Next
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close
```

Comment: basic algorithm: scan through the file until you find the deadlock line, then output the next two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Marc B's idea in **simple** code:

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(sTxt) : qq = """" & sTxt & """" : End Function

Const csFind  = "Error: Deadlock"
Dim nLines : nLines   = 3
Dim bFound : bFound   = False
Dim tsIn   : Set tsIn = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("..\data\Text-1.txt")
Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
   Dim sLine : sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
   If bFound Then
      WScript.Echo sLine, "=>", qq(Trim(Split(sLine, "=")(1)))
      nLines = nLines - 1
      If 0 = nLines Then Exit Do
   Else
      bFound = sLine = csFind
   End If
Loop
tsIn.Close
```

Output:

```
type ..\data\Text-1.txt
Error: Deadlock
Param 0 = xyx
Param 1 = 22332244
Param 2 =
Param 3 = 1
Param 4 =
Error: This is no Deadlock
Param 0 = abc
Param 1 = def
Param 2 =
Param 3 = ghi
Param 4 =

DNV35 E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\9812373\vbs
cscript 00.vbs
Param 0 = xyx => "xyx"
Param 1 = 22332244 => "22332244"
Param 2 = => ""
```

"simple" means "exactly what is needed to solve the problem - no more, no less".

1. A decent script needs "Option Explicit" to guard against typos in
   variable names.
2. If you don't use the create and format parameters of the .OpenTextFile method, you don't need the iomode parameter ForReading (it's the default).
3. If you search for constant/fixed strings, RegExps are just an error prone overhead.
4. If you want to match "Deadlock" using the pattern "deadlock", you need .IgnoreCase (proves 3)
5. If you don't want to match "Error: This is no Deadlock", you need a more elaborate pattern (proves 3 again)
6. There in no need for the objFSO variable, if you use the object just once; same holds for strSearchString (why emphasize 'string' twice but hode the 'search in' vs. 'search for' difference?)
7. In your case, .Count is either 0 or 1 - I assume the there are no lines like "Error: Deadlock 1, Deadlock 2, and another deadlock"; to deal with more than one match, you'd have to specify .Global.
8. Looping over the matches collection makes no sense for your problem - either you got the triggering "deadlock" line or not.
9. A script to search for a triggering line and then do something needs at least one state (bFound and nLines in this case) to do different actions for the lines depending on properties of lines seen before and now long forgotten.
10. After the 'something' there is no need to process the file further.